# Does the command to heed the sanhedrin apply today?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, derabanan, maseches-sanhedrin

In the times of the Sanhedrin (High Court in Temple times) there was a commandment to heed their words (Deut. 17:11).

> According to the law which they shall teach you, and according to the judgment which they shall tell you, you must do; you shall not turn aside from the sentence which they shall declare unto you, to the right hand, nor to the left

Does this precept apply regarding the greatest Torah scholars of the generation?

Comment: dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68208/how-much-weight-must-we-give-to-the-council-of-sages-opinions

Comment: It is not clear for me if the question is about the verse or the diverse drashot in bavli, sifri and yerushalmi. "אפילו יגידו לך על ימין שהוא שמאל, זה  הבבלי או יכול אפילו יגידו לך... זה הירושלמי""

Comment: or if there is the lav of lo tassur

Comment: @Lee might be  a duplicate indeed although I saw this one more focused on individual Rabbanim, the other more focused on councils of gedolim. But maybe this is not relevant

Comment: @mbloch also this is asking specifically about Dt 17:11 and the other more generally.

Comment: The Sefer HaChinuch famously applies this to scholars of each generation. Other Rishonim, such as Rambam do not.

Comment: In sefer Hachinuch 495 the main verse is Deut 17, 10, and  Deut 17, 11 is a redundancy to reinforce the importance of the mitsva, So, I suggest to modify the OP. The Chidush of the verse 11 is Lo Tasuru (Chinuch 496).  The fact that the verse 11 is writed in the OP may lead to confusion. @mevaqesh,  this is only for gzerot, minhagot, perush shekiblu.

Comment: @kouty I saw your edit changing the verse in the question to 17:10 but I think it is difficult to do so without asking the OP if this is what he meant. He wrote 17:11 so you can suggest he also looks at 17:10, but changing it goes a bit too far in my personal view. Let's see how others see it

Comment: @mbloch
The Sifrey cited also the verse 11 to say "ועשית. מצוות עשה". But The original commandment is the verse 10. But its is OK for not changing. See my first comment as a testimony of the confusing effect of the verse 11.

Comment: @kouty I don't dispute the content, you might well be right, my only point was that changing a question as fundamentally as changing the basic verse it asks about should be raised with the OP first - like you did here

Comment: @mbloch OK (:|] very good

Answer (score 1):

In a [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68208/how-much-weight-must-we-give-to-the-council-of-sages-opinions), I [cited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68208/how-much-weight-must-we-give-to-the-council-of-sages-opinions/68258#68258) a very interesting article by Dr Eli Turkel in Tradition [(The nature and limitations of rabbinic authority)](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2027/No.%204/The%20Nature%20And.pdf). He writes there (pp. 83-84)

> […] **community leaders only have religious authority if they are
>   followed by a majority of the community** […] In modern times, no
>   single organization is accepted as authoritative by al Torah observant
>   Jews and, as a result, **no group has the right to impose its views on
>   individuals who do not voluntarily accept them**. […] Hence we
>   conclude that a modern rabbi’s authority is limited to his immediate
>   community or to those people who ask his opinion. No rabbi has the
>   right to impose his views on anyone else. (see also bottom of p. 86)

In conclusion he writes (p. 95)

> **We have shown that in the absence of a Great Sanhedrin, a court […] or
>   even a gadol hador can impose their halakhic opinions only if they are
>   accepted by the majority of a community.** Even in that case, the
>   decisions affect only that specific community and not others.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so what community does Eli Turkel, a professor of mathematics represent?

Comment: @ray I do not know what community he represents. Modern Orthodox I would guess as he is a working talmid chacham. I am not sure if you are challenging the fact that we are citing a professor of mathematics (and not a rav). In any case the value of what he writes should be judged based on the content and as you might have seen he brings plenty of references from gemara, Rishonim and Achronim. But maybe I didn't fully understand your comment

Comment: see also [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68258/11501) with comments bringing quotes from others incl. the Baal Hatanya !

Comment: I am not able to judge based on the contents as there may be other words from chazal who say the opposite. would feel alot better to seeing something from the likes of Rav Moshe Feinstein which is true daas torah

Comment: @ray then you might enjoy [this](http://www.zootorah.com/RationalistJudaism/DaatTorahLichtenstein.pdf) from R Lichtenstein zl (the son in law of the Rav, R Soloveitchik). He starts from the same verse as you (p. 4) and brings R Aharon Feldman (haredi Rosh Yeshiva of Ner Israel in Baltimore)

Comment: @ray and maybe in the future, if you want specific sources (e.g., haredi only, or R Moshe Feinstein only) you could specify that in your question

Comment: just looking for a traditional source, ie one of the gedolim. earlier the better

Comment: @ray And as mbloch said, that should be noted in the question.