# "Rabbi Shopping" - how often and for what can one change his Rabbi

Tags: halacha-theory, rabbis

*The other question ["rabbi-shopping"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71598/rabbi-shopping) asks about asking a single question to two Rabbis.*

This question addresses the possibility of changing the personal ruling Rabbi time to time. Assuming a person wholeheartedly and exclusively follows his current Rabbis rulings:

1. How often can one change his Rabbi?
2. What are the reasons a person can turn from his current Rabbi to another?
3. Are there differences between different communities (Litvakes, Hassidish, Sefardish)?

Comment: Changing which town you live in is an obvious one.